# Question regarding "distance function" in convex spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Assume that we have a convex space $K < \mathbb{R}^n$ and a point $a \not\in K$. I need to show that there is a function in the dual, $f\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(a)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in K$.

I first consider  the case where $a\not\in \bar{K}$ (the closure of $K$). Let $a'$ be the point of minimal distance from $a$ in $\bar{K}$. This point exists because $K$ is convex. Then I know that $f$ can be given by $a-a'$.

My question is, how can I extend this to the whole space?

Edit: I think I have to approximate this $a$ by $a_n\not\in\bar{K}$, but the details elude me.

Comment: If you define $f$ to be $a - a'$, it is already defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, isn't it?

Comment: @gerw I took $a$ as being outside the close of $\bar{K}$ (which is always closed, so $a'$ exists). I'm trying to see what happens when $a$ is in the boundary.

Comment: I overlook the bar over $K$...

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of tangent/normal cones to $K$?

Comment: @gerw unfortunately, no

Comment: Then you might want to have a look at seperation theorems (consequences of Hahn-Banach).